# An unnecessary '0' at the end of my output

Tags: java, time-complexity, priority-queue

Whenever I run my program, it adds a 0 at the end and I cannot seem to make it to not do that. I tried asking Chegg but they all just put it into ChatGPT and give me the same incorrect answer over and over again so I am coming here for help. For reference, the user input of '4' should produce the output:

```
8000
23700
50000
```

but my code outputs:

```
8000
23700
50000
0
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Quantiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("");
        k = scanner.nextInt();

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Incomes.txt"));
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                list.add(Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Collections.sort(list);

        int n = list.size();
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
        int i = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < k; j++) {
            int nextIndex = j * n / k;
            while (i < nextIndex) {
                pq.offer(-list.get(i));
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println(-pq.peek());
        }

        while (i < n) {
            pq.offer(-list.get(i));
            i++;
        }

        while (pq.size() > 1) {
            pq.poll();
        }

        System.out.println(-pq.peek());
    }
}
```

Tried user input -> 4
Expecting:

```
8000
23700
50000
```

Got:

```
8000
23700
50000
0
```

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: No idea what your code is doing or what is in `Incomes.txt`, but... if `k` is `4`, then you have three `println` inside your `for` loop, and one at the end of your function, for total of four outputs. Removing the last line seems like it would give you the output you want.

Comment: use print() instead of println() at this line System.out.println(-pq.peek());

Comment: Getting rid of the last print statement fixed it, thank you very much!

Comment: You called your class `Quantiles`. If it is supposed to calculate quartiles when the input is 4, it seems to me that you may be doing double work by first sorting the list of numbers and then putting the numbers into a priority queue. Can’t you make do with sorting alone if you select the correct indices from the sorted list?